# HTML italics and non-italics text is rendered too close to each other

Tags: html, css, fonts, rendering

There is a rendering issue with text marked as *italics* when no extra space is added after the italicized text and before the next text span (non-italics):

```
Eureka!
```

[image]

```
<span style="font-style: italic">Eureka</span>!
```

[image]

which makes *exclamation mark* being rendered too close to the last italicized character *a*.

Engine: Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit)

On the other hand MS Word inserts some extra space and mixed text looks nice:

[image]

vs

[image]

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not just include the punctuation inside the italics?

Comment: What font are you using? Also to note that the i tag is really for emphasis not necessarily italics. font-style italic would be more sure to get proper italics if the font has them ( just a comment, not saying this solves your exclamation mark problem)

Comment: @mplungjan It results in a short space after, not a big difference. Looking for a generic explanation/solution.

Comment: @AHaworth I am using Open Sans, but it doesn't depend on a particular font, I've checked. Also *i* is just for simplicity in here. The actual markup is CSS-based.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just to note that using tag i is not the same as using CSS font-style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `letter-spacing` in your CSS. This can give you a hint how to style your document:

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.tag {
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="tag">Eureka</span>!
```

Comment: Hmmm... letter-spacing just changes the distance between letters, doesn't it? Not sure if it solves the problem stated.

Comment: Yes, it does add spacing to characters. However, it's a bit unfair to compare how a browser and Word display text, as they both generate it differently and may depend on settings - for example, I just tried your example in my copy of Word (looks like you used Times New Roman font there) and for me the exclamation mark also was pretty close to the text, much closer then in your screenshot. So in case of CSS, your best choices are either `letter-spacing` or `margin` set to 1 or 2 px: https://jsfiddle.net/avzL5of7/1/

Comment: @lgal Fair enough! MS Word rendering result is just used as a visual reference of what "looks right" in this case. Actually printed version is quite similar to what Word does and what is expected in the e-version too.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to be able to reproduce your problems with Open Sans. But it seems you are using a badly kerned version. At least, I think it the kerning that determines the space between specific glyphs, but I'm unsure whether that's true for different font styles, even in the same family. But maybe Chrome decides not to kern. In that case you can ask it to kern normally, using [font-kerning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning).

I don't think letter-spacing solves your problem, because that's about the spacing between all glyphs.

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}
.problem {
  font-style: italic;
}
.hack {
  margin-right: 0.1ex;
}
.kern {
  font-kerning: normal;
}
```

```html
<span class="problem">Eureka</span>!<br>
<span class="problem hack">Eureka</span>!<br>
<span class="problem kern">Eureka</span>!<br>
```

Comment: The keyword to solution was “to reproduce”. Found out that the issue was improper font loading. You can see that both “a”s at my screenshot are similar, while they should be quite different when italics and not italics. Bounty goes to you. Thanks for providing a hint to solution!